# MvvmCross migration causing a Xamarin Custom iOS View Presenter issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

While creating a `CustomIosViewPresenter` (of type MvxIosViewPresenter), in MVVMCross 5.x, there was a `Show` override that I was able to use to get the `IMvxIosView` so as to update the UIViewController presentation style using the PresentationValues from the ViewModel.

I had this code and it worked:

```
// Worked before
public override void Show(IMvxIosView view, MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    if (request.PresentationValues != null)
    {
        if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("NavigationMode") &&
            request.PresentationValues["NavigationMode"] == "WrapInModalWithNavController")
        {
            var vc = view as IModalPresentation;
            vc.ModalPresentationAttribute = new MvxModalPresentationAttribute
            {
            WrapInNavigationController = true,
            ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen,
            ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
            };
        }
    }
    base.Show(view, request);
}
```

But after migrating to MvvmCross 7.1, the older override doesn't work anymore and I have to use this instead, but there is no view passed into the Show override, how do I get it?
I tried this code below, but `view` is null and it's not able to cast it this way `var view = viewType as IMvxIosView;`

```
// Doesn't work now
public override Task<bool> Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    if (request.PresentationValues != null)
    {
        if (request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("NavigationMode") &&
            request.PresentationValues["NavigationMode"] == "WrapInModalWithNavController")
        {
            var viewsContainer = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
            var viewType = viewsContainer.GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);
            var view = viewType as IMvxIosView;
            
            var vc = view as IModalPresentation;
            vc.ModalPresentationAttribute = new MvxModalPresentationAttribute
            {
                WrapInNavigationController = true,
                ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen,
                ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
            };
        }
    }
    return base.Show(request);
}
```

The reason I need this is because without this function when I close the special flow of view controllers that need this, its not closing all the view controllers in that flow, it closes only one of them at a time.

[image: Image to supplement the question]

Comment: Which presentation attributes are you using on this ViewController? Why are you not controlling the presentation style through attributes?

Comment: @Cheesebaron This was an existing app that I was helping migrate. So the view controller has no attributes, I tried to individually add the attributes to the view controllers in the flow, but it didn't work as they were not behaving as one set of modal. They were behaving as individual modals, and closing the modal, just closed one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Feel for the developers that will come after you and build stuff the right way

So I dug into the [MvvmCross MvxIosViewPresenter source code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/72eff48d54a7d48ef614e8b4094219867e53ab03/MvvmCross/Platforms/Ios/Presenters/MvxIosViewPresenter.cs) and was able to use this new override CreateOverridePresentationAttributeViewInstance()

I needed the request object to see the presentation values so I updated the `Show` function that gets called before the other override as follows:

```
MvxViewModelRequest _request;
public override Task<bool> Show(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    _request = request;
    return base.Show(request);
}
```

And I was able to get the ViewController this way, in order to selectively present it as a modal:

```
{
    var view = base.CreateOverridePresentationAttributeViewInstance(viewType);
    if (_request.PresentationValues.ContainsKey("NavigationMode") &&
_request.PresentationValues["NavigationMode"] == "WrapInModalWithNavController")
    {
        var vc = view as IModalPresentation;

        vc.ModalPresentationAttribute = new MvxModalPresentationAttribute
        {
            WrapInNavigationController = true,
            ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverFullScreen,
            ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
        };
        return vc;
    }                    
    return view;
}
```

And then the closing of the modal was another challenge, that I was able to figure out using the `TryCloseViewControllerInsideStack` and `ChangePresentation` overrides

Answer (score 1):

What you would normally do with MvvmCross if you want to navigate within a Modal ViewController is firstly add a `MvxModalPresentationAttribute` to the modal that will host the rest of the navigation where you set `WrapInNavigationController` to `true`.

For the children, it would just be regular child navigation, no attributes needed.

If you then want to control how the modal is popping you would create your own `MvxPresentationHint` and register it in your presenter using `AddPresentationHintHandler`.

Then you would in your ViewModel where you want to change the presentation call `NavigationService.ChangePresentation(your hint)`.

As for the Presentation Hint, it should probably just call `CloseModalViewControllers` and that would probably do what you want.

Comment: and is there a way I would be able to possibly load the flow from a specific page instead of from the beginning?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here

Comment: ! I was able to figure it out. I t was painful indeed :D